# Prevent Windows 10 from installing OneNote printer

Tags: windows-10, printer, office365, microsoft-onenote

OneNote printer is a nightmare for me. I removed it from Printers countless of times. It always comes back. Sometimes as a default printer, sometimes as a regular one. How can I get rid of it once and for good?

I have only found [this seven years old answer](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/783862-stop-onenote-2013-printer-installing), but it is for Office 2013 and Windows 7. I have Windows 10 and Office 365. I have opened GPO, but all the entries and menu items are completely different than in given answer.

Comment: What is your printer issue? I just ignore it and assign the correct default printer.

Comment: @John I did this about five dozen times so far. That's the issue. To cite myself: "_Sometimes it appears as a default printer_". Sometimes = way too many times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> After looking at your skill level @trejder , I rewrote this post.

---

### First, the simple worry free way. I am not sure how long these changes will last. Perhaps permanent?

1. Open your device manager
2. Open "Print queues"
3. One at a time, right click the OneNote entries and choose "Uninstall device"

### Now, the "driver guy" way:

***WARNING, don't be careless.  You are playing with drivers***

First, I am going to give a brief primer on how this all works.

- A driver author writes an inf to install their goodies. In this specific case, The OneNote installer installs a "print queue" driverish thingy from `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OneNote\prnms006.inf`
- Windows copies this inf to c:\windows\inf and renames it with a name that starts with `oem` and ends with a unique number like `oem25.inf`.
- There are also built in drivers that don't have unique inf files but are still part of your driver tree. (as you will see below).  An instance of this might be something like a keyboard or usb flash drive.
- We are going to use the `pnputil` command to make this all go away.  First, we are going to use it to get a list of what is installed, then we will use it to clobber those entries.

***Lets get started cleaning house! :)***

***You can assume that ALL of these commands are from an elevated command prompt.***

1. Go to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16` and rename OneNote to *_OneNote_* (its just the driver, not the app).  This is to prevent office from kicking off the install again in the future and making a NEW oemXXX.inf.  Of course an upgrade will put it back. :(
2. Run `pnputil /enum-drivers >%temp%\oem_drivers.txt`
3. Run `pnputil /enum-devices >%temp%\drivers.txt`
4. Open %temp%\oem_drivers.txt in your handy dandy text editor and search for `prnms006.inf`.  Note the name of the oemXX.inf file that it is coupled with.
5. Open %temp%\drivers.txt and search for OneNote.  Note the all `Instance ID` strings.

***NOW ITS CLOBBERIN' TIME!!***

1. run `pnputil /delete-driver oemXXX.inf /uninstall` where (of course) oemXXX.inf is the one you took down.
2. run `pnputil /delete-driver oemXXX.inf /force` where (of course) oemXXX.inf is the one you took down.  This might give an error but we do it becuase I have had the first one fail to actually delete the driver package.
3. run `pnputil /remove-device INSTANCE_ID_STRING_HERE` for each OneNote `Instance ID` found in drivers.txt

You should be clean.
You should not require a reboot for this kind of driver.

This technique will for to force uninstall ANY kind of OEM driver (like realtek or HP thingamajiggers too!).

Comment: This answer couldn't be better. Exact, professional and a funny in the same time. Thank you, thank you, thank you. I am formatting my IHM (In Head Memory) to remember that I should start a bounty in the next 22 hours and give you some rep, because this is one of the best answers for all my questions in the entire SE I've read so far. Thx!

Comment: Happy to help @trejder .. thanks for the kind words.

Comment: As noted above, it did come back eventually, due to Windows updates. I've had success in the past preventing updates from doing this by
1. Deleting everything inside that OneNote directory (rather than renaming it)
2. Right-click on that OneNote directory, select Properties
3. On the Security tab, click Advanced
4. Take Ownership
5. Disable Inheritance, removing all inherited properties.
This leaves the directory unreadable / writeable by _anyone_, (even you). You can revert by re-enabling inheritance, but it should stop an upgrade from reinstating it. So far so good for me, anyway.

Comment: Thanks. Leave it to Microsoft to decide our choice of system default printer should not always be the chosen system default printer. LOL!

Answer (score 4):

I noticed in the other solution the pnputil unstinall 1 step needs to be flipped from:
pnputil /delete-driver /uninstall oemXXX.inf
To:
pnputil /delete-driver oemXXX.inf /uninstall

I discovered this as I wrote out a powershell to help automate the OneNote Printer uninstaller:

```
$officeFolder = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\' -Filter Office* | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
$currentPath = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\'+$officeFolder+'\OneNote'
$newPath = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\'+$officeFolder+'\OneNoteOLD'
Rename-Item $currentPath $newPath


$drivers = pnputil /enum-drivers
$drivers -split '\r?\n' | select-string -Pattern "prnms006.inf" -Context 1,0 | % {
    $pubName =  $_.Context.PreContext[0]
    }
    $pubName


$regex = 'o\w*'

$oem = $pubName | select-string -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value }
$oem = $oem+'.inf'

pnputil /delete-driver $oem /uninstall
pnputil /delete-driver $oem /force




$devices = pnputil /enum-devices
#take devices, split the lines with returns, match all lines with one note and include the line above 
$devices -split '\r?\n'  | select-string -Pattern "OneNote" -AllMatches -Context 1,0 | % { 

    #select 1 line above the match line
    $instId = $_.Context.PreContext[0]
    #clean up instance iD
    $instId = $instId.substring($a.length - 52, 52)
    #unstinall
    pnputil /remove-device $instId

}
```

Comment: You can (and should) edit other users answer in such case. There's an `Edit` button below it. Your script is still useful, so no need to delete this answer.

Comment: I have taken your advice and fixed my answer.  I also popped you +1 for writing such a nifty script.