# Removal of RealTek family controller

Tags: drivers

Re: Realtek GBE ethernet family controller:
I have done everything by the book to deal with the issue. I have uninstalled and reinstalled this on my computers multiple times.

Background: I went from Optimum 300 (NJ) to their "upgraded" 1000 service (Altice) and then this item suddenly appears and blocks my ability to search the net through Google.

I have both computers directly connect via ethernet cable.I have wifi but the cable connect is far better which a speed test verifies.
Here, I get a notification that my cable is not properly connected when this is active on the system.

First of all I don't need another lecture from some Microsoft dilettante telling me that I shouldn't delete or disable this driver because it would somehow harm my computer(s). It doesn’t.

Both computers are fully functional with it either disabled or uninstalled. Again, I can't search the net when this is on the system installed and/or reinstalled so it's not an outdated driver issue.

I have learned to either disable or uninstall it via at least 2 different ways but it reappears as active on my two Lenovo computers (one laptop & one mini desktop).

Both computers have windows 10. Is there something simple dear god that I am missing to stop this from reinstalling?

I am tired of going through the process of either disabling or uninstalling it each time I turn the computer on (and actually sometimes even when I leave the computers on).

Optimum tech support (which I can barely understand between the mumbling and accents) is about as incoherent and useless with this as they are about their outtages which occur but supposedly can’t trace.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please give your post a structure that is not one long sentence.

Comment: See my post [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1719698/prevent-windows-10-from-installing-onenote-printer/1719710#1719710). Ignore that it is about print drivers. The concept is the same.  It tells you how to remove drivers.  If it shows up again.. [Disable Automatic Driver Updates](https://wethegeek.com/how-to-disable-automatic-driver-updates-in-windows-10/).. then re-do the driver removal.  Why I said to do it twice is because auto-driver-updates is USUALLY a good thing and affects ALL drivers.  If this fixes, let me know and I will post as answer.

Answer (score 1):

For what it is worth:

1. Find out the driver executable name (maybe rtkdrv.exe or similar ?)
2. Investigate how to get access to the windows policy editor (it was a looong time since I used it)
3. Create a policy that prohibits running the executable.

*A loong time ago I stopped the "sticky keys" accessability item disturbing me in this way (I often had my left hand rest on the shift key, which makes it pop up)*

Comment: This is a nice trick @Hannu.  Could one not also just change the permissions on the file itself?

Comment: I have not tried that, but think: The installation needs to be done in "admin mode", it might be hard to find (other) "permissions" that stops that.