# Windows 10 refuses stop readding printer

Tags: windows, windows-10, printing, workstation

We several months back replaced the main network printer due too it jamming excessively, and for the first month or 2 everything has worked fine. Now one of the computers has begun too re-add the old printers too itself for no reason i can see. Every time I remove it, it will respawn again.

Printers are shared from and pushed out from the DC, and i have removed the driver and all instances of the old printers from here, and the group policy which pushes out printers are only pushing out the correct ones, but this pc ONLY adds a bunch more (Including duplicates of the new one)

I have tried :

- Removing them from the really useless "printers and scanners" UI within windows 10.
- Uninstalling them from device manager.
- Deleting everything from printers and even all the drivers from `C:\Windows\System32\Spool\Drivers` and all from the print queue.
- Checking if they are in registry (Couldn't see them there)
- Removing the computer from the domain and putting it back on.
- Different users.
- Checked appwiz.cpl for any software which might be adding them back due to old config.
- Checked startup for anything which could be re-adding them.

And none of these things have had any impact on the issue.

I checked properties in device manager on them to see what is adding them and all I got was
Under location:
`\Users\S-1-5-21-1288031120-1378624092-2130640294-1174\Printers\^\^\[DC name]^`

And when i go under details configuration ID says:

```
printqueue.inf:PRINTENUM\LocalPrintQueue,NO_DRV_LOCAL
```

When I go into notepad and try too print to one of these they are not visible.

What am i missing here? Is this just a particularly irksome windows 10 bug again, or is there another way to remove these printers that I've not tried?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Windows on the troublesome PC?

Comment: Not yet, this would be troublesome as it's got a bunch of propitiatory software/devices on it. Including drivers for some specialist equipment which are always a real problem to get back.  So this action is kinda my last ditch effort.

Comment: See my answer to a different problem (and yet not).. It might very well help. 
 https://superuser.com/questions/1719698/prevent-windows-10-from-installing-onenote-printer/1719710#1719710

Comment: Does [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/968749/8672) help?