# How do I uninstall an unused Windows driver?

Tags: windows, drivers

I have been trying to get rid of an older version of the graphics driver on my brothers laptop, but it's pretty much impossible to do so. I tried using numerous methods, I tried PowerShell, I tried the device manager, but I just can't manage to get rid of it.

On all my other devices I get the option in device manager to show devices by driver, which lists all the .inf files and very easily lets me remove those drivers that are installed but not used by anything, however annoyingly this option is completely missing from my brothers laptop. When using powershell and doing get-windowsdriver, I can see the driver is installed but I don't know how to uninstall it. I can't delete the folder from the driver store as it's protected by System and I don't want to force delete it using iObit unlocker or something as I want to properly get rid of the driver.

This issue is very annoying, there must be an easy way but not a single website on Google gives me something that works. The laptop is running Windows 10 22H2 so I don't understand why device manager doesn't have the option to show all devices by driver, maybe it's a setting in the registry somewhere as this was a feature added a while back and it's present on my laptop that's on 20H2. There are 2 AMD graphics drivers in the driver store folder, each 1.1GB which totals 2.2GB, installed by AMDs adrenaline software. Does anyone have ideas on how I can get rid of the extra driver?

Comment: What does Device Manager report when trying to uninstall in Device Manager.  2GB for a device suggests possibly a bad device. It may be necessary to back up and reinstall Windows 11 to get rid of it.

Comment: Can you be more specific with regards to what exactly your attempting to remove from your system by editing your question?

Comment: If [Display Driver Uninstaller](https://www.guru3d.com/files-details/display-driver-uninstaller-download.html) doesn't uninstall it then you should not try to uninstall it. IMHO.

Comment: Very likely this is a x-Y problem. Why do you think you need to un8istall said driver instead updating it? That "takes up 2GB" is incorrect, no driver uses that much. Additional/complementary software (many would call it 'bloatware') may use hundred of MB but the driver itself definitely not even 1/10 of what you think it does. Please [edit] and post a better description along with hardware specifications.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1719698/prevent-windows-10-from-installing-onenote-printer).  The method is the same.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get the driver uninstalled after a bit of trying stuff. What I had to do was:

1. Open device manager.
2. Right click the graphics adapter driver.
3. Choose update driver.
4. Click search for drivers on my computer.
5. Click I want to choose from a list of installed drivers.
6. Select the old driver and click next, then click close.
7. Right click the graphics adapter driver.
8. Choose remove driver.
9. Check try to remove the driver for this device and click uninstall.

For me after waiting a bit it automatically activated the correct driver again, but it might use the default basic graphics driver again. If it does you need to repeat step 1-4 and then select the correct driver.
I hope it can help someone.