# Bluetooth chip showing as Unknown USB Device - can't get Windows to recognise it

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, bluetooth

I'm on Windows 10. I was using the default Windows Bluetooth drivers, but tried installing the manufacturer ones. They were worse, so I uninstalled them again.

After the uninstall, the Bluetooth device stopped showing in device manager entirely. There is now an "Unknown USB Device (Device Descriptor Request Failed)" entry which I assume corresponds to the Bluetooth device. Through a series of unfortunate events, my system restore points were lost.

I want to get the default Windows driver for the bluetooth back. It doesn't recognise the device, so Windows can't do this automatically. I've tried doing the "Browse my computers for drivers" thing, but that doesn't offer me anything that would match Bluetooth. I've tried reinstalling the manufacturer drivers, thinking this would at least get the device recognised, but nothing changed.

I've even tried reinstalling Windows 10 (via "Reset this PC"), which I fully expected to work. However, after the reinstall, it still only shows up as an unknown USB device.

I've found suggestions online to do things like uninstall all of the listed USB devices (or just the "eXtensible Host Controller") and to restart the machine, but that hasn't worked in my case.

Where do I go from here?

Comment: Hello, which device is it? Which Bluetooth card? You need to be way more specific.

Comment: @Destroy666 I'm actually not sure precisely. This is quite an old machine, and the generic Windows bluetooth driver which it had previously didn't identify the device. I believe it's probably a Broadcom device.

However, I'm not sure it should matter much. Windows previously picked it up automatically and used its own driver. I just want that to happen again - which I was sure reinstalling Windows would achieve!

Comment: What do you mean you're not sure? How did you download the manufacturer drivers then? You shouldn't attempt to install anything until you're 100% sure you know what the device is. You can find it out in many ways on various systems. E.g. https://www.windowscentral.com/how-find-computer-model-number-windows-10 or in BIOS.

Comment: @Destroy666 This is an ancient laptop circa 2012 (Lenovo Z580), and the manufacturer doesn't provide Windows 10 drivers for this model. I was planning to reinstall windows afterwards anyway, so I acted recklessly and tried experimenting with Windows 8 drivers from similar-era-but-different Lenovo laptops. It actually worked - those drivers functioned, but were buggy dropped out quite often. I knew this was risky, but figured that nothing I did would matter after I reinstalled Windows anyway.

Comment: I think you need to modify your question heavily with all of these (and any other) very important details that weren't stated anywhere, otherwise this will be closed for lack of clarity quite quickly.

Comment: @Destroy666 Why are these things important, if Windows found it automatically before?

I basically just want to reset whatever I've done to the default state, so that Windows can do its thing. My assumption is that that's a device-agnostic problem.

Comment: @Destroy666 There are online reports of people seeing very similar/same problems on various machines with various Bluetooth devices - but none that have a clear working solution. However, I think this is a general device-nonspecific problem.

Comment: @Destroy666 I'm expecting an answer to have a form like "There's certain driver information that survives a soft reinstall in X cache - run this command to reset, and reinstall again" or something.

Comment: Because this is a Q&A website which is supposed to serve other people and even for own sake, if you want to get accurate replies, you ask an accurate question. https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask Not stating that you installed drivers for wrong version of Windows is basically a "crime" type of detail skip here.

Comment: @Destroy666 I have since completely reinstalled Windows. Those past incorrect drivers should no longer be an issue, right? All of the drivers for my other devices were properly reset by the reinstall process.

Comment: For Bluetooth it may and likely is an issue. Many years ago there was a situation with a Dell laptop not miles away from what you did with yours. It had Win7 pre-installed with a downgrade option to XP. We noticed that those that were downgraded and later reinstalled with Win7 the Bluetooth was kaput. It was confirmed as something expected by Dell's support and the Bluetooth was replaced in warranty. It seems the firmware injected by the older OS drivers made it impossible to be later reversed. Sound familiar? Fortunately for you a much better and newer USB BT is dirty cheap.

Comment: In Device Manager, right-click the unknown device, select Properties, Details tab, select from the drop-down list "Hardware IDs". What values do you see?

Comment: See my answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1719698/prevent-windows-10-from-installing-onenote-printer/1719710#1719710) if all else fails.  This should get you to pre-install configuration.  My answer is for a stupid print driver but the method should be the same.  Read down to the second and third block.  I believe that I have given sufficient information on how to rid yourself of accidental driver installation.  These will be no different.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Thanks, that worked perfectly! If you'd like to put this as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is answered by a very non obvious duplicate and marked as such, and op is unlikely to come back and improve their question.

Comment: @music2myear I approve of your close vote. The only reason I didn't delete it myself is because I apparently don't have permission to. However, I don't think the question is as bad as people were suggesting. The "be more specific" thing proved a red herring, and in fact the device-nonspecific answer I got was what I wanted. IMO, that actually makes this a more generally useful question.

If you'd prefer me to improve the question I can, but making the suggested change (give more details about specific device) would actually be worse.

Comment: Improving questions is always a good idea and strongly encouraged here under almost every circumstance. Showing how this apparently different situation is still solved by that other is good and worth demonstrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1719698/prevent-windows-10-from-installing-onenote-printer/1719710#1719710).  I would duplicate that answer here but that would be confusing and if I even need to update the other answer, I want it in one spot.

This should get you to pre-install configuration.

The answer I provided before was for a stupid print driver but the method should be the same.

Read down to the second and third block.

I believe that I have given sufficient information on how to rid yourself of accidental driver installation.

These will be no different.