# How to return to original USB driver?

Tags: windows, usb, drivers, libusb

I am struggeling to get some [communication via USB using PyUSB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77564963/7295599) (help there is also very much appreciated). For me, the documentation of [PyUSB](https://pypi.org/project/pyusb/) does not cover the full picture (including such traps and time-consuming annoyances. The minimal examples do not work in my case. During the annoying trial and error process, I also used [Zadig](https://zadig.akeo.ie) to force a certain driver.

[image]

[image]

The communication was working with the [Keysight IO Libraries Suite](https://www.keysight.com/us/en/lib/software-detail/computer-software/io-libraries-suite-downloads-2175637.html), however, I want to use PyUSB in my own programs.
Due to forcing another USB driver (`libusbK`) via Zadig, the Keysight Suite doesn't work anymore. However, now it seems I can't go back to the original driver which was installed when installing the Keysight IO Library Suite. Re-installation or reparing of the Keysight Suite does not help.

How to get the Keysight Suite back to work? Which file do I maybe have to delete manually or which Registry entry to change? Any hints appreciated!

Comment: Can't you use Zadig again to select the standard default Windows driver?

Comment: @ChanganAuto Do you mean `WinUSB (v6.1.7600.16385)`? That's what I tried. Keysight Suite will not work with this one. And Keysight Suite doesn't seem to install the driver which was installed on the "clean" Windows system.

Comment: If you can find the serial device in Device Manager then it might have a "roll back" option that could work... https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhGwT.png

Comment: @Mokubai thank you for your suggestion. But I think I have re-/de-/installed the different drivers so many times, that the original one is certainly lost. I can only check tomorrow,

Comment: You might try actually REMOVING any 3rd party driver you added using [this method](https://superuser.com/questions/1719698/prevent-windows-10-from-installing-onenote-printer/1719710#1719710) that I describe in a different answer (it should be the same solution).  Then re-scan for devices and it should pick the windows one back up.

Comment: @Mokubai this "roll back" option apparently works only for the previously installed driver, but not for many installations before.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas There are about 223 files in C:/Windows/INF which have changed since I started with Zadig two days ago. About 34 of them are .inf files. And I guess I have identified the one `oem45.inf` which is from Agilent/Keysight which seemed to have installed the original driver `ausbtmc.sys`. Can't I simply somehow force this driver to be installed again?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems it was easier than expected:

- Device Manager
- Device in question (right mouse click)
- Update driver
- Browse my computer for drivers
- Let me pick from a list of available drivers on my computer
- Select USB Test and Measurement Device (IVI) (which is `ausbtmc.sys`). Luckily, this driver was still on the list.

[image]

What puzzled me and made me feel unsure...

- the first time I changed the driver with Zadig it took forever and Zadig stopped with the message that driver (`libusbK.sys`) installation failed (at least, I got entertained by Zadig status messages ;-). But the new driver was apparently installed nevertheless. Pretty strange!
- after having changed the driver with Zadig, and trying to get back to the original driver (`ausbtmc.sys`), why the Keysight software did not install their original driver when re-installing it?